# TIdHTTPServer with TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL doesn't return when Active is set to FALSE in Debian console

Tags: linux, delphi, console, indy10, debian-stretch

I'm setting a web server with Indy and Delphi 10.3.1 in a console application running in Debian. I can't gently shutdown the server setting IdHTTPServer.Active to FALSE because it never return and the only way to close the application is to press ctrl-c or kill the process. I tested it in windows and is ok so I think the problem is Indy with linux.

```
program SrvDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  IdContext,
  IdSSL,
  IdCustomHTTPServer,
  IdHTTPServer,
  IdSSLOpenSSL,
  IdServerIOHandler,
  Posix.Base,
  Posix.Fcntl;

var
  CERT_PATH: string;
  HTTPServer: TIdHTTPServer;
  ServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL: TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL;
begin
  CERT_PATH:='/opt/test_certs/';
  HTTPServer := TIdHTTPServer.Create;
  ServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL:=TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create;
  try
    HTTPServer.DefaultPort := 4123;
    ServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.SSLOptions.CertFile:=CERT_PATH+'server.crt';
    ServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.SSLOptions.KeyFile:=CERT_PATH+'server.key';

    HTTPServer.IOHandler:=ServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL;
    HTTPServer.Active := True;

    Writeln('Server ON - Press any key to stop ...');
    Readln;
    Writeln('Passed ...');
  finally
    Writeln('Passed ...');
    HTTPServer.Active := False;       // --> it hang here
    Writeln('Never passed ...');    
    ServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Free;   // --> never passed 
    HTTPServer.Free;                  // --> never passed
  end;

  Writeln('Server OFF');              // --> never passed

end.
```

I tried to debug and I noted that the problem happens only with SSL and TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL and if I put a breakpoint in line LListener.WaitFor (**procedure TIdCustomTCPServer.StopListening** of **IdCustomTCPServer.pas**) the connection close gracefully, perhaps because of the time to start again the program is sufficient to let him close the connection. If I don't put the breakpoint the program lock there.

```
//APR-011207: for safe-close Ex: SQL Server ShutDown 1) stop listen 2) wait until all clients go out
procedure TIdCustomTCPServer.StopListening;
var
  LListenerThreads: TIdListenerList;
  LListener: TIdListenerThread;
begin
  LListenerThreads := FListenerThreads.LockList;
  try
    while LListenerThreads.Count > 0 do begin
      LListener := {$IFDEF HAS_GENERICS_TThreadList}LListenerThreads[0]{$ELSE}TIdListenerThread(LListenerThreads[0]){$ENDIF};
      // Stop listening
      LListener.Terminate;
      LListener.Binding.CloseSocket;
      // Tear down Listener thread
      LListener.WaitFor;   //  --> BREAKPOINT HERE
      LListener.Free;
      LListenerThreads.Delete(0); // RLebeau 2/17/2006
    end;
  finally
    FListenerThreads.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What you describe typically happens if a deadlock occurs while Indy is waiting for an internal worker thread to terminate itself. I don't have Linux to test with, and am not a Linux dev anyway (not that I could debug it if I wanted to, as my dev machine died recently). You are going to have to debug into Indy's source code to see what it is really waiting on.

Comment: `LListener.WaitFor()` simply waits for that `LListener` thread to fully terminate. If `WaitFor()` hangs, it means the thread is not terminating. That is what you need to debug into further. The previous `LListener.Binding.CloseSocket()` closes the thread's socket description, which *should* abort any pending socket operations that are blocked, and cause subsequent socket operations to fail. Though, it is known that on Nix platforms, closing a socket from one thread is not *guaranteed* to abort a socket operation that is blocked in another thread. So maybe that is what you are running into.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but said that I don't know how to debug further because if I stop the program in WaitFor() the socket closes without problem and if I let him to go when I try to pause it, the debugger asks for the path to libc.so.6 source file, is there any trick I can do to shutdown the server without to kill the process?